# Server 2008 R2 slowness, GUI lag, slow file access

Tags: performance, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a box with Windows Server 2008 R2 on it that is running extremely slow.

GUI lag is so bad it can take several minutes just to open up an explorer window for example. Explorer crashes. File access is very slow from connected users. Etc.

Specs:

- RAM: 16GB
- CPU: Intel Xeon
- Disks:

  - C: 1TB (This has the server OS as well as SQL Server.)
  - D: 1TB (This is two 1TB disks in RAID 1 holding user data.)
- Roles:
  AD, GP, DHCP, DNS

What I've checked/noticed:

- CPU utilization never really gets above 30%. Average over the space of a day is roughly 2%.
- RAM is at 55% utilization. Most all of that of course being used by SQL Server.
- Network utilization averages <2%
- Disk stats for 5 minutes perfmon while server is symptomatic:

  - C: Avg. Idle %: ~99%
  - D: Avg. Idle %: ~99%
  - C: Avg. Disk Queue Length: Between 0 and 0.015.
  - D: Avg. Disk Queue Length: Between 0 and 0.023.
- In Resource Monitor, I cannot pull a list of processes that are running. Nor can I see any disks. It's all just blank white boxes no matter how long I give it to load the data.
- Rebooting the box makes the machine run perfectly. It's always when I come in in the morning that it's slowed back down.
- Checking the event log doesn't show any obvious tells as to what's causing this. The only thing I spotted was the classic "The winlogon notification subscriber  took 464 second(s) to handle the notification event (Logon)." error. But that really only serves to let me know that the server is in fact running slow.

I'm dying over here trying to figure out what's causing this. Any ideas or help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Despite just about every metric telling me the disks were running fine, replacing the disks ultimately fixed the issue. I guess I'll never know why they were behaving like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issuee.

.. and I checked my settings by running this command

```
netsh interface tcp show global
```

Also if you just want to test by disabling it run this

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled
```

to set it back run this

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=normal
```

Worth a try but you could/should reboot the server after making the change..

... and when I only disabled it, my server performance was fixed.